# Getting buttons to open different URLs in webview

Tags: android, button, webview

I have a screen with about fifteen buttons. Each button is supposed to open a specific url in a webview on another screen (which is set up as an activity). How can I make the webview display the right url based on the button that was clicked?

Here's my code for the buttons:

```
package com.adanawtn.FunnMagViewerWindow;

import com.adanawtn.funnmagviewerwindow.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class mainactivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
Button logobtn;
Button twitterbtn;
Button instagrambtn;
Button topeyebtn;
Button bestbtn;
Button gearsbtn;
Button artsbtn;
Button travelbtn;
Button eventsbtn;
Button dailybtn;
Button magbtn;
Button bttmeyebtn;
Button tvbtn;
Button mallbtn;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);


        Button twitterbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitterbtn);
        Button instagrambtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.instagrambtn);
        Button topeyebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topeyebtn);
        Button bestbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bestbtn);
        Button gearsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gearsbtn);
        Button artsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.artsbtn);
        Button travelbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.travelbtn);
        Button eventsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eventsbtn);
        Button dailybtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dailybtn);
        Button magbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.magbtn);
        Button bttmeyebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttmeyebtn);
        Button tvbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvbtn);
        Button mallbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mallbtn);


 // logo            
      logobtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent logoClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com"));
                startActivity(logoClick);      
 }});


  // twitter
                twitterbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg1) {

                        //Starting a new Intent

                        Intent twitClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/funnmagazine"));
                        // starting new activity

                        startActivity(twitClick);      
     }});
// instagram                    
                    instagrambtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg2) {

                            //Starting a new Intent

                            Intent instClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/funnmagazine"));

                            // starting new activity

                            startActivity(instClick);      
         }});

// topeye
                        topeyebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg3) {

                                //Starting a new Intent

                                Intent topClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com"));

                                // starting new activity

                                startActivity(topClick);      
             }});

    // best
                            bestbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View arg4) {

                                    //Starting a new Intent

                                    Intent bestClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com/la"));

                                    // starting new activity

                                    startActivity(bestClick);      
                 }});
        // gears
                                gearsbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View arg5) {

                                        //Starting a new Intent

                                        Intent gearsClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com/gear"));

                                        // starting new activity

                                        startActivity(gearsClick);      
                     }});
// arts
                                    artsbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View arg6) {

                                            //Starting a new Intent

                                            Intent artsClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com/art"));


                                            // starting new activity

                                            startActivity(artsClick);      
                         }});

// travel
                                        travelbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View arg7) {

                                                //Starting a new Intent

                                                Intent travelClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com/travel"));

                                                // starting new activity

                                                startActivity(travelClick);      
                             }});
 //events
                                            eventsbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View arg8) {

                                                    //Starting a new Intent

                                                    Intent eventsClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com/events"));


                                                    // starting new activity

                                                    startActivity(eventsClick);      
                                 }});
//daily
                                                dailybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(View arg9) {

                                                        //Starting a new Intent

                                                        Intent dailyClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com/daily"));

                                                        // starting new activity

                                                        startActivity(dailyClick);      
                                     }});
    // mag
                                                    magbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onClick(View arg10) {

                                                            //Starting a new Intent

                                                            Intent magClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com/blog"));


                                                            // starting new activity

                                                            startActivity(magClick);      
                                         }});
// bttmeye
                                                        bttmeyebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onClick(View arg11) {

                                                                //Starting a new Intent

                                                                Intent bttmClick = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Class1.class);

                                                                // starting new activity

                                                                startActivity(bttmClick);      
                                             }});
 // tv
                                                            tvbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onClick(View arg12) {

                                                                    //Starting a new Intent

                                                                    Intent tvClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com/funn-tv"));

                                                                    // starting new activity

                                                                    startActivity(tvClick);      
                                                 }});

    // mall
                                                                mallbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onClick(View arg13) {

                                                                        //Starting a new Intent

                                                                        Intent mallClick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://funnmag.com/mall"));

                                                                        // starting new activity

                                                                        startActivity(mallClick);      
                                                     }});



 }

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

And here is the code for the activity that holds the webview:

```
package com.adanawtn.FunnMagViewerWindow;

import com.adanawtn.funnmagviewerwindow.R;


import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Class1 extends Activity {

 @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_class1);


 WebView webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);


Intent logoClick = getIntent();
    String uri = logoClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(uri);

Intent twitClick = getIntent();
    String twituri = twitClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(twituri);   


Intent instClick = getIntent();
    String insturi = instClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(insturi);  

    Intent bestClick = getIntent();
    String besturi = bestClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(besturi);  

    Intent gearsClick = getIntent();
    String gearsuri = gearsClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(gearsuri);     

 Intent artsClick = getIntent();
    String artsuri = artsClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(artsuri);  

    Intent travelClick = getIntent();
    String traveluri = travelClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(traveluri);    

 Intent eventsClick = getIntent();
    String eventsuri = eventsClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(eventsuri); 

 Intent dailyClick = getIntent();
    String dailyuri = dailyClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(dailyuri);     

 Intent magClick = getIntent();
    String maguri = magClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(maguri);   

    Intent tvClick = getIntent();
    String tvuri = tvClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(tvuri);    


Intent mallClick = getIntent();
    String malluri = mallClick.getStringExtra("uri");
    setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl(malluri);  


}


}
```

Comment: In Class1 you have twelve times the four code lines getIntent()-loadUrl(). One will do.

Comment: In mainactivity make all new intents like Intent bttmClick = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Class1.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) like this example:

```
Intent instClick = new Intent(this, Class1.class);
instClick.putExtra("uri", "http://instagram.com/funnmagazine");
startActivity(instClick);
```

Then, the code you have in the webview activity should work, but you only need one of the little sections of code that you're using to set up the webview instead of all fifteen.

Comment: So I can just use one snippet for the webview even though each button/intent has a different name?

Comment: Yes, because the names of the button and the intent objects are not passed along with the intent. If you use the same name for the extra (e.g. uri) you should be fine with just the one snippet.

Comment: So how would I label the intent in the webview activity? Would it be something like this:

` Intent getClick = getIntent();

        String uri = getClick.getStringExtra("uri");

        setContentView(webview1);

        webview1.loadUrl(uri);
`

Comment: The name is not relevant. Just use `Intent intent = ....` to keep it general. And setContentView() is not needed as you already did that before. Unless you have a special reason.

Comment: @SyrupandSass If all you need from the intent is the extra, you can just use `String uri = getIntent().getStringExtra("uri");`. That way you don't have to worry about naming it.